# Cognos Analytics - connect to database

Tags: dashboard, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I'm experimenting with the dashboard functionality of Cognos Analytics. However, I do not know how to make a connection between the source of the data (the application) and Cognos, so that the data refreshes automatically. Also, I'm not able to find any decent documentation on this topic. Can anybody describe this procedure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a package or data module source the data will refresh if the refresh timer is set and the cache is disabled.

The following link explains this in more detail:
https://barrachd.co.uk/insights/blog/cognos-analytics-r11-latest-release/